# How to update a config map in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap, kubernetes-deployment

Hi I am using a config map which is created from the files in a directory.
The config map is mounted to the volume in the pods container. sometimes i need to update my config map . Any idea how can i do it ?. currently i am deleting the config map and recreating it and then restarting the pods. not sure if it is the best way because, here we delete and create a config map.

here is the shell script code

```
kubectl create ns k6
kubectl create configmap k6-scripts-configmap -n k6 --from-file /test/scripts/k6/
kubectl apply  -f /test/config/k6/k6-deployment.yaml
```

later in the script i need to update the config map as some files in the directory (`/test/scripts/k6/`) needs to be changed.

```
kubectl delete configmap k6-scripts-configmap -n k6
kubectl create configmap k6-scripts-configmap -n k6 --from-file /test/scripts/k6/
kubectl rollout restart deployment k6 -n k6
```

could you let me know if i am doing it correctly , or is it possible i can update the config map without deleting it ? Also after an update should i restart the deployment ?

thank you

Comment: Can you not just do `kubectl edit cm k6-scripts-configmap`?

Comment: Refer this [blog](https://faun.pub/update-configmap-without-restarting-pod-56801dce3388#:~:text=Updating%20the%20config%20map%20in,t%20work%20if%20subpath%20used.) by Harsh Manvar helpful to resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use four methods to update configmaps.

**Method : 1**
You can use below command to update configmaps

```
kubectl create configmap k6-scripts-configmap -n k6 --from-file /test/scripts/k6/ -o yaml --dry-run=client | kubectl apply -f -
```

**Method : 2**
As explained in the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#replace)  you can use `Kubectl replace` also.

Note :  kubectl replace fails if a configmap does not already exist.

**Method : 3**

As Chris Gillatt suggested you can use  `kubectl edit configmap <cfg-name>`

**Method : 4**

Refer this [blog](https://faun.pub/update-configmap-without-restarting-pod-56801dce3388#:%7E:text=Updating%20the%20config%20map%20in,t%20work%20if%20subpath%20used.) by Harsh Manvor for information on auto updating configmap without restarting POD.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the Deployment and the ConfigMap definition in 2 different files.

Then, update only the configmap:

```
kubectl create configmap k6-scripts-configmap \
  -n k6 --from-file /test/scripts/k6/ \
  --dry-run -o yaml > configmap.yml
```

Apply the changes:

```
kubectl -n k6 apply -f configmap.yml
```